# How to see selected method's full name on Xcode completion popup

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode8

I'm trying to implement a delegate method in Xcode, and I see many methods looking very similar as their names/signatures are truncated:

[image]

For example, there's no way to distinguish which method is selected and which method is the one right below the selected one, and this is just one example. I have the same problem whenever there's a delegate involved with long method names and I'm trying to implement one of its methods. The popup is meant to be useful and in cases like this, it's extremely counter-intuitive.

Is there any way to display/distinguish the full method names?

Comment: Default `NSTableView` behaviour: Hover the mouse pointer over the row. Works on the first 8 lines (bug?) in my version of Xcode which has … at the end of the line.